# Here I am trying to return array of files but it returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here in below function I am trying to return a file, but its returning undefined while searching for files, it returns undefined. Where I am performing search and getting S3 objects and preparing array of object for further sending email purpose.

```
        const send_email = async(data) => {
          try {
         
            const data_attachment = await get_S3_files(batch_key);
        
            console.log(data_attachment)
            
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
          }
        }
    
    const get_S3_files = (data) => {


 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var params = {
          Bucket: S3_bucket,
          Delimiter: '',
          Prefix: `${data}/`
      }
      var files = []
      s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (data.Contents.length) {
              for (const row of data.Contents) {
  
                  await s3.getObject({ Bucket: 'name', Key: row.Key }, function (err, data) {
                      if (err) {
                          console.log('S3 Get Object Error', err)
                          reject(err)
                      } else {
                          console.log(data)
                          files.push({
                              filename: data.Body,
                              content: data.Metadata.file_name,
                          })
  
                      }
                  })
              }
          }
      });
      
      resolve(files);
  })
}
```

EDIT-

1. REMOVED AWAIT
2. Kept return in function section

ISSUE: ITS RETURNING EMPTY ARRAY BEFORE THE FUNCTION GETS EXECUTED.
[image]

Can anyone help here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are passing Bucket: 'name', is this correct bucket name?

Comment: Unfortunately just putting await in front of a callback function will convert it into a promise.  You need to promisify listObjects, getObject etc.

Comment: You are conflating asynchronous programming patterns, that is, you are using `async/await` and callbacks, which may not exhibit the behaviour you desire. If you want to use `async/await` remove the callback function from s3.`listObjects` and call `.promise()` on `listObjects`, otherwise, remove the `await` before `s3.listObjects`

Comment: @ethane Did that, But its returning the empty before the fucntion is gets executed

Comment: @Keith Can you help there? Seems like I don't really have good knowledge of promisify listObjects with getObjects....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with a race condition. It is returning even before waiting for the array to be fill.

I think this solution might work.

```js
const send_email = async (data) => {
  try {
    const data_attachment = await get_S3_files(batch_key);

    console.log(data_attachment);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const get_S3_files = (batch_key) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var params = {
      Bucket: S3_bucket,
      Delimiter: "",
      Prefix: `${batch_key}/`,
    };

    s3.listObjects(params, async function (err, data) {
      var files = [];
      if (err) throw err;
      if (data.Contents.length) {
        await Promise.all(
          data.Contents.map((row) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              s3.getObject({ Bucket: S3_bucket, Key: row.Key }, (err, data) => {
                if (err) return reject(err);
                files.push({
                  filename: data.Body,
                  content: data.Metadata.file_name,
                });
                return resolve(data);
              });
            });
          })
        );
      }
      return resolve(files);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Your solution ,It return empty array [] before it gets executed.

Comment: Upadated question

Comment: @ZeusCarl I have updated the snippet. Can you please check with this one? Please require s3 as well.

Comment: ` TypeError: this.makeRequest is not a function` throws this error

Comment: For which line you're getting this error? You can get it from the stack trace.

Comment: unable to trace it, Seems like lib has some issue with 8.17 node version

Comment: Which library is it?

Comment: `util` library I am getting an error, can you try making it using `aws-sdk` only

Comment: @ZeusCarl I have removed the util library, can you check now.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from the wrong place. Your return statement is inside `s3.listObjects` function. The `return files;` should be one line below just before closing the function. But, it is not gonna work anyway. You have to promisify the function.

```
const get_S3_files = (data) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var params = {
            Bucket: 'name',
            Delimiter: '',
            Prefix: `${data}/`
        }
        var files = []
        s3.listObjects(params, async function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (data.Contents.length) {
                for (const row of data.Contents) {
    
                    await s3.getObject({ Bucket: 'name', Key: row.Key }, function (err, data) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('S3 Get Object Error', err)
                            reject(err)
                        } else {
                            console.log(data)
                            files.push({
                                filename: data.Body,
                                content: data.Metadata.file_name,
                            })
    
                        }
                    })
                }
            }

            resolve(files);
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Yes, but returns empty array before the functions gets executed, check my updated question.

Comment: @ZeusCarl Your updated code will not work. Read my answer properly. You have to promisify the function.

Comment: Check now, I also put picture of empty array. Its comming before the `get_S3_files` even gets executed...

Comment: @ZeusCarl Update the answer. See `resolve(files);`.

Answer (score 0):

The below code-snippet might not necessarily answer the original problem, but if OP is open to bring some drastic changes to his code, then I think this solution would work perfectly without affecting the original functionality.

```
const get_S3_files = async (data) => {

    var params = {
        Bucket: 'name',
        Delimiter: '',
        Prefix: `${data}/`
    }
    var files = []
    await s3.listObjects(params, async function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (data.Contents.length) {
            for (const row of data.Contents) {
                try {
                    const dataContent = await s3.getObject({ Bucket: 'name', Key: row.Key }).promise();
                    files.push({
                        filename: dataContent.Body,
                        content: dataContent.Metadata.file_name,
                    })
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log('S3 Get Object Error', err);
                }
            }
        }
        return files;
    });
}
```

Using callback everywhere will make the code unreadable. I'd suggest you convert your response to promise using [promise()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html) with s3 sdk's methods.

Similarly, You can convert `listObjects` method to promise. It'll make code more readable.

**Note**: I've added few variables from my end into the code, please make sure to change them according to your code context.

Comment: It return empty array [] before it gets executed.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check if it works for you.